# Output PHP response as XML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

Newbie here. I have AJAX requesting XML data. Since it's cross-domain, it's going through a PHP proxy. The issue is that the proxy returns the XML in the form of a string. This makes it hard to parse in Javascript. How can I 1) have the PHP return the data in the form of an XML object or 2) convert the string to XML after it is returned?

```
$.ajax({
url: 'proxy.php',
data: {requrl: request + '&reportType=' + report}
    })
   .done(function(response) {
   ...
   }
```

proxy.php:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents($_GET['requrl']);
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: `{requrl: request + '&reportType=' + report}` should be `{requrl: request, reportType: report}`

Comment: try to add `dataType` : `url: 'proxy.php', dataType:'xml'`

Comment: As long as you don't provide an example URL and some example data this is far too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the xml directly like so...

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
echo $file;
```

If you want to parse the xml with php look into [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can load XML from a string using the [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) function:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_GET['requrl']);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

Or directly load the XML file into the string, like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_GET['requrl']);
```